# Using iif expression in groupings

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, msbi

I have a main grouping and sub grouping,and sub grouping should be based on IIF Condition,I am using a direct (IIF(x="a"),"b","c") but i am not getting data grouped properly in report not sure of the reason.

I am sure that my iif statement is correct,because it is populating correct data in textboxes but when i use in grouping expression it is failing.

Not sure weather there is any restrictions on grouping expressions in ssrs or something.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If this `(IIF(x="a"),"b","c")` is any indication, then you are using `IIF` incorrectly. It should be `IIF(x="a","b","c")`.

Comment: Other than your syntax error/typo that RR pointed out, the theory you're using should work as you expect. `=IIF(Fields!MyFIELD.Value = "A", "B", "C")` If **MyField** is **A** then **B** else **C**.

Comment: thanks.i am using IIF in grouping where iif(x="Some string",should be grouped on field,Nothing),Not working on grouping expression..By default  grouping is done on at least one row even the iif condition is not satisfying.

Comment: Have you tried putting your iif statement in a data column just to make sure it is actually returning the proper 'a' or 'b'?

Comment: Thanks.Figured out that the else part in the IIF Condition shouldn't be "Nothing"  while using in group expression.used some constant in place.

Comment: Just an another question.i have a tablix with  main group A and child group B now i need to have an another grouping at B level itself not as child with another field.is that possible.